# JRE listening on wrong IP address

Tags: java

I have some servers with two network adapters (one is used for general traffic and the other is used ONLY for backup traffic).  I am running the latest JRE to support a remote deployment application.  When I connect to the servers via this deployment application, I get an error that it can't deploy to the IP of the backup network adapter, which would be expected.  I removed the adapter, and reinstalled Java, then re-added the adapter and it seemed to work UNTIL I rebooted the machine, and the JRE seemed to "bind" to the backup adapter again.

Not knowing much about Java, how does the JRE chose which IP to use as the default (and how do you change that?)

Comment: Can you share with us logs, codes

Comment: Your server software would have this as a configuration parameter, like all server software.

Comment: A Java application will use whichever adapter the application specifies. If it binds to the wrong address, it's a bug/misconfiguration in the application, it's got nothing to do with the JRE.

Comment: What if the application doesn't specify?  How is an IP / Adapter then chosen?  Unfortunately I don't have the source code (just compiled jars) as this is a COTS deployment program.  I've scoured the various conf and properties files and unfortunately I don't see an option to specify an IP.  I do have a support request out to the vendor but was hoping to figure it out as they take a while to respond.

Comment: If unspecified, it binds to 0.0.0.0 which means all interfaces.